# Has the 10k deleted list lost the distinction between posts I can undelete and those I can't?

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, deleted-posts

I was rummaging through mSO's 10k tools recently. I decided to look through the 10k deleted list (to see what the latest programming question was), and noticed posts deleted by a moderator (or that I otherwise can't vote to undelete) are no longer shown greyed out.

[image]

Could we please add that back in?

Comment: Note that it seems to be isolated to mSO; I couldn't repro on Space.

Comment: Which ones do you actually want to undelete? :)

Comment: @TheGrinch I'm really interested in face-tracking, actually.